# Remote connection to as400 with python

Tags: python-3.x, db2, ibm-midrange

I am trying to connect to a db2 database in AS400 through python3 remotely. I am not able to get through the error message. I am running in spyder IDE in windows OS.

```
import ibm_db
conn=ibm_db.connect(f"DATABASE=xxxx;HOSTNAME=xxxx;PORT=21;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=xxxxx;PWD=xxxxx;",'','')

connState = ibm_db.active(conn)
print(connState)
```

Error message

> SQLCODE=-30081][CLI Driver] SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP".  Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".  Location where the error was detected: "10.248.11.78".  Communication function detecting the error: "connect".  Protocol specific error code(s): "10061", "*", "*".  SQLSTATE=08001

I did refer the document https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/sql30081n-tcpip-communication-errors but unable to make progress. I am new to this kind of connection and would appreciate the help.

**Edit**
As suggested in the comments. I used `pyodbc`to successfully connect to db2 database and now I am trying to call a stored procedure.
My stored procedure has 3 required in(all numeric) and 2 out(both alphanumeric) parameters

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={iSeries Access ODBC Driver}; '
       'SYSTEM = xx.xxx.xx.xx;'
        'Hostname=xxx; '
        'Port=21; '
        'Protocol=TCPIP; '
        'Database=MYLIB; '
        'UID=xxxxx; '
        'PWD = xxxx;'
        ,autocommit=True) 

cur = conn.cursor()
params = ("072220","0306529","10000")
cur.execute("{CALL MYLIB.MY_SP (@param1name=?, @param2name=?, @param3name=?)}",params)
```

**Error message**

> ('HY000', '[HY000] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0440 - Routine MY_SP in MYLIB not found with specified parameters. (-440) (SQLPrepare)')

Does this mean I am not passing my parameters right?

Comment: Have you checked what the doc you linked to tells you to check for the `10061 - ECONNREFUSED` error that you're getting?  What were the results?

Comment: Double check the port-number used for Db2 on the i-series, and verify you have a Db2-connect license file on the Windows workstation in the clidriver license subdirectory.

Comment: @Charles - the ECONNREFUSED test told me my port was wrong. I was able to connect to the server by port 21. But the error in python stays the same with port 21

Comment: @mao - I don't have the Db2-connect license. How do I get one?

Comment: Buy db2 connect

Comment: Db2 Connect is an expensive product and provides basically no advantage over the free ODBC driver (you may already have it; if not, look for IBM i Access Client Solutions). Once you have ODBC installed, you can then use pyodbc from Python.

Comment: @ayadav Agree with JohnY remark. Cheaper option is to install `IBM i access` product (which already has the relevant license) and has an OBDC option. Your port number may still be incorrect, defaults may be 446 (unencrypted) 448 (encrypted), but may be changed at your site. This is not programming, it is site specific configuration. Talk with your __i admin__ person.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was able to connect to the database. However, I am getting error while executing my stored procedure in the DB. I have updated my question. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured the problem was the way I defined parameters. I need "0" for output parameters

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={iSeries Access ODBC Driver}; '
       'SYSTEM = xx.xxx.xx.xx;'
        'Hostname=xxx; '
        'Port=21; '
        'Protocol=TCPIP; '
        'Database=MYLIB; '
        'UID=xxxxx; '
        'PWD = xxxx;'
        ,autocommit=True) 

cur = conn.cursor()
params = ("072220","0306529","10000",0,0)
cur.execute("{CALL MYLIB.MY_SP (?,?,?,?,?)}",params)
```